# how to solve version conflict error in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, service

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 20
        versionName '6.7'
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/droidText.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    // compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    // Glide image library
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
     //implementaion 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
    compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2') {
        exclude module: "com.google.code.gson"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude '.idea/compiler.xml'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

}
```

Here I have defined `Gradle` with firebase and `play service` related libraries. Previously I used `Firebase 9.0.0` version, now that is not taking firebase key. So I have updated to new version, then started getting below issue. First I updated `firebase` library only, but error is shown like `playservice` and firebase must maintain the same version. Problem is `playservice` related gradle change time. (Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0. )

Comment: If u r using targetSdkVersion=27 then u must use libraries with version 27. Like, targetSdkVersion=26 then  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

Comment: Formatted and corrected grammatical errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google-service plugin problem is because you're using not the same version for firebase and google play service with:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
```

it should be:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
```

Then, you also need to move the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the bottom of your build gradle like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
   ...
}

   ...

dependencies {
   ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

You also need to only use only one version of dependencies. In your project you're using:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'

compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2') {
    exclude module: "com.google.code.gson"
}
```

that is a redundant. You need to use only one:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

Last, you don't need to add the following:

```
compile files('libs/droidText.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
```

because the following line is already included all of them:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Comment: thanks. it's helpful for me. me move to apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' bottom of gradle it's working

Comment: Hi, me faced another issue after update android studio (now android studio 3.2 Canary 7) apk proguard time shows following warning and not proguard apk com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza 
retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find superclass or interface rx.Observable$OnSubscribe 
retrofit.client.OkClient$1: can't find superclass or interface com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody etc...

Comment: Please create another question if the problem and cause is totally different then your above question. Btw, you should avoid using Canary version because it sometimes introduce bugs. Avoid wasting your time using a non-stable release for your works.